# The parent argument in the uvm_component constructor

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I expected `my_child` to inherit the `say_hello` function from `my_parent` in the following code, but it did not.

Can someone explain to me what exactly `parent` argument does?

```
class my_parent extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(my_parent);
  
  function new(string name = "my_parent", uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction: new
  
  function void say_hello;
    $display("Hello, UVM!");
  endfunction: say_hello
endclass: my_parent
/*========================================*/

class my_child extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(my_child);
  
  function new(string name = "my_child", uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction: new
endclass: my_child
/*========================================*/

module top;
  my_parent p;
  my_child c;
  
  initial begin
    p = my_parent::type_id::create("p", null);
    c = my_child::type_id::create("c", p);
    c.say_hello;
  end 
endmodule: top
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up the terms *parent* and *child* with the principals of class inheritance. They are distinct objects. A parent *creates* a child, and the `uvm_component` represents a hierarchal family tree in a database. Each component you create has a handle to its parent, and the parent has a list of handles that are its children.

```
class my_child extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(my_child);
  function new(string name = "my_child", uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction: new
endclass: my_child
class my_parent extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(my_parent);
  my_child child;
  function new(string name = "my_parent", uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction: new
  function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase;
     child = my_child::type_id::create("child", this); // 'this' is the parent object
  endfunction : build_phase
endclass: my_parent
module top;
  my_parent p;  
  initial begin
    p = my_parent::type_id::create("p", null);
  end 
endmodule: top
```

When using inheritance, we have *entended* or *derived* classes, they are not the children of the base class.

```
import uvm_pkg::*;
`include "uvm_macros.svh"
class my_child extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(my_child);

  function new(string name = "my_child", uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction: new
  task  run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    $display("Hello, UVM!, from base");
  endtask: run_phase
endclass: my_child
class my_parent extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(my_parent);
  my_child child;
  function new(string name = "my_parent", uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction: new
  function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    child = my_child::type_id::create("cchild", this); // 'this' is the parent object
  endfunction : build_phase
endclass: my_parent
class my_child_extended extends my_child;
  `uvm_component_utils(my_child_extended);

  function new(string name = "my_child", uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction: new
endclass: my_child_extended
module top;
  my_parent p;  
  initial begin
    my_child::type_id::set_type_override(my_child_extended::get_type());
    run_test("my_parent");
  end 
endmodule: top
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the `my_child` class from the `my_parent` class instead of `uvm_component` when you want to inherit from the `my_parent` class.  Change:

```
class my_child extends uvm_component;
```

to:

```
class my_child extends my_parent;
```

When you make this change and run the simulation, it prints the following, as expected:

```
Hello, UVM!
```

The `parent` variable is explained in the [UVM Class Reference](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1d/html/index.html) document under `uvm_component`.